# How to ignore HTMLUnit warnings/errors related to jQuery?

Tags: java, htmlunit

Is it possible to teach HTMLUnit to ignore **certain** javascript scripts/files on a web page? Some of them are just out of my control (like jQuery) and I can't do anything with them. Warnings are annoying, for example:

```
[WARN] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument:
getElementById(script1299254732492) did a getElementByName for Internet Explorer
```

Actually I'm using JSFUnit and HTMLUnit works under it.

Comment: The HTMLUnit mailing list would be a good place to ask. The developers are on it, and they're generally very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid exceptions because of any JavaScript errors:

```
 webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Comment: Or for 2.13 and above:    `webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Well I am yet to find a way for that but I have found an effective workaround. Try implementing `FalsifyingWebConnection`. Look at the example code below.

```
public class PinConnectionWrapper extends FalsifyingWebConnection {

    public PinConnectionWrapper(WebClient webClient)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        super(webClient);
    }

    @Override
    public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
        WebResponse res = super.getResponse(request);
        if(res.getWebRequest().getUrl().toString().endsWith("/toolbar.js")) {
            return createWebResponse(res.getWebRequest(), "",
"application/javascript", 200, "Ok");
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

In the above code whenever HtmlUnit will request for toolbar.js my code will simply return a fake empty response. You can plug-in your above wrapper class into HtmlUnit as below.

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
new PinConnectionWrapper(webClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WebClient.setScriptPreProcessor](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setScriptPreProcessor%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptPreProcessor%29). It will give you the opportunity to modify (or in your case, stop) a given script before it is executed.

Also, if it is just the warnings getting on your nerves I would suggest [changing the log level](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/logging.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in ignoring all warning log entries you can set the log level to INFO for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument in the log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

Insert this code.